# Export CSV or PDF Based On Datatables Laravel 4

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, csv, datatables

I have a datatables which contains the data retrieved from database. When I enter some keywords into search textbox (the search textbox is generated by datatables), the result of the table will be changes. This is good. But when I click export to csv or pdf, the result in csv or pdf will be retrieved from database instead of datatables.

How to export to csv/pdf based on the datatables plugin using laravel?

//datatable plugins

```
<link href="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

//php

```
public function sales_csv(){    

    // columns      
    $arrSelectFields = array(
        -- columns --
    );

    // query
    -- sql queries --

    // passing the columns which I want from the result set. Useful when we have not selected required fields
    $arrColumns = $arrSelectFields;

    // define the first row which will come as the first row in the csv
    $arrFirstRow = $arrSelectFields;

    // building the options array
    $options = array(
        'columns' => $arrColumns,
        'firstRow' => $arrFirstRow,
    );
    // creating the Files object from the Utility package.
    $Files = new Files;
    return $Files->convertToReportsSalesCSV($query, $options);
}
```

Comment: can use datatables plugin `tableTools` to get csv locally

Comment: @charlietfl i referred to this https://www.datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/ and tested. i entered keyword, but it still export the whole result

Comment: Can you use dompdf library or you have to stick with datatables?

Comment: @mdamia will check out dompdf later. I used datatables because it has built in sorting and search function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would probably post the keyword to my server and run the sql query again filtering those results and then create the csv/pdf

Comment: thank you MorningDew. I write the csv button in a form and set all the filter conditions as hidden fields then pass to laravel. THANK YOU! :D

Answer (score 4):

One way you could do it is to use jQuery and make an ajax call.

Firstly, give the table an ID. Next, get the table itself and get its HTML using this bit of code:

```
var html = $('#myCoolTable').html();
```

Then make an ajax call to Laravel to generate the PDF passing through the HTML. You can use this HTML to PDF library: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/

You should then get back the PDF with the exact table you had on screen (with any filters etc).

As a sidenote, you can also add your CSS to the HTML to give to the PDF library and it will even style the table to be the same too!

Hope this helps.